# Using strip() on string removes prefix that does not match the argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, strip

The string (expressed as UTF-8 bytes),

```
b'\xe8\xb0\x81\xe6\x98\xaf\xe8\xb0\x81\xe7\x9a\x84\xe5\x91\xa8\xe6\x9d\xb0\xe4\xbc\xa6'
```

does not begin with

```
b'\xe6\x98\xaf\xe8\xb0\x81'
```

However, using `strip()` on it below does remove this prefix. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Apr 19 2021, 17:20:37) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> "谁是谁的周杰伦".strip("是谁")
'的周杰伦'
>>> bytes('是谁', encoding='UTF-8')
b'\xe6\x98\xaf\xe8\xb0\x81'
>>> bytes('谁是谁的周杰伦', encoding='UTF-8')
b'\xe8\xb0\x81\xe6\x98\xaf\xe8\xb0\x81\xe7\x9a\x84\xe5\x91\xa8\xe6\x9d\xb0\xe4\xbc\xa6'
```

Comment: Do you mean https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complex Unicode codepoints in your question make this a bit more confusing than needed. Consider this simpler example:

```
>>> "abcde".strip("ba")
'cde'
```

[`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) is working as intended. The argument to strip is an iterable of characters, not a complete string. Prefixes and suffixes consistently entirely of *any* of the characters passed in *any* order get removed.

Quoting the docs:

> The outermost leading and trailing chars argument values are stripped from the string. Characters are removed from the leading end until reaching a string character that is not contained in the set of characters in chars. A similar action takes place on the trailing end.

If you want to remove an exact prefix, use [`str.removeprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.removeprefix):

```
>>> "谁是谁的周杰伦".removeprefix("是谁")
'谁是谁的周杰伦'     # no match, bad order

>>> "谁是谁的周杰伦".removeprefix("谁是")
'谁的周杰伦'        # match
```